# ERROR Method cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

Error al compilar:

- Akerra.java:6: **error: method introduccion** in class  Akerra cannot
  be applied to given types;
          introduccion();
          ^   required: int   found: no arguments   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
- Akerra.java:7: **error: method estribillo** in class Akerra cannot be
  applied to given types;
          estribillo();
          ^   required: int   found: no arguments   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

(2 errores)

```
public class Akerra{
public static void main(String args[]){
int versos=1;
   while(versos<=4){ //Cuatro versos

         introduccion();
         estribillo();
         partefinal();

   versos++;
   }      
}

public static void introduccion(int versos){
   switch(versos){
         case 1:
            System.out.println("Akerra ikusi dugu baratzean jaten.");
            System.out.println("Makila ikusi dugu aker hori jotzen.");
         break;
         case 2:
            System.out.println("Sua ikusi dugu makila erretzen.");
            System.out.println("Ura ikusi dugu sua amatatzen.");
         break;
         case 3:
            System.out.println("Idia ikusi dugu ur hori edaten.");
            System.out.println("Soka ikusi dugu idi hori lotzen.");
         break;
         case 4:
            System.out.println("Sagua ikusi dugu soka hori eteten.");
            System.out.println("Katua ikusi dugu sagua harrapatzen.");
         break;
   }
}
public static void estribillo(int versos){
      if (versos>3){
         System.out.println("Katuak sagua, saguak soka,");
      }
      if (versos>2){
         System.out.println("Sokak idia, idiak ura,");
      }

      if ( versos > 1){
         System.out.println("Urak sua, suak makilak,");
      }

      if ( versos > 0){
         System.out.println("Makilak akerra, akerrak artoa,");
      }

}

public static void partefinal(){
   System.out.println("Akerra ken.");
   System.out.println("Baratzetik akerra ken,");
   System.out.println("Ken, ken, ken, ken.");
   System.out.println("");
}
}
```

Comment: El mensaje es claro, los métodos `introduccion()` y `estribillo()` esperan un entero como parámetro, pero los estás llamando sin pasarle dicho parámetro. Posiblemente es el valor de `versos` el que debes pasar ¿? Sería entonces así la llamada: `introduccion(versos);` y `estribillo(versos);`

Comment: Al definir tus funciones nombraste un Entero que les tendrías que mandar, pero al llamar a dichas funciones no les mandas nada.

Comment: Así es. Compila sin errores añadiendo el entero al llamar el método e introduccion y estribillo. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No esta pasando los parametros a los metodos correspondientes tendria que ser de esta manera:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
int versos=1;
   while(versos<=4){ //Cuatro versos

         introduccion(versos); //aquí es donde debes de pasar la variable versos como parametro
         estribillo(versos);  //y aquí también
         partefinal();

   versos++;
   }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al llamar a tus funciones deberías de llamarlas de la sgte forma:

```
  introduccion(versos);
  estribillo(versos);
  partefinal();
```

con eso ya no debería de darte errores.

Comment: Ahí dará error en `partefinal`  el cual no requiere parámetros.